# Entity Framework Long To Int Conversion

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an application connecting to two databases; one for the application, and one that contains standardized lookup data.  The issue with the second database is one table has a `bigint` for the PK, while everything else is `int`.  So this messes with one of my queries as I'm trying to do:

```vb
'.ID is int, c.ID is long
From c in ctx.Lookup
Where c.IsActive = True
Select New ReferenceItem With { .ID = c.ID, .Text = c.Text }
```

The issue here is that I can't change this one table as it's referenced by several apps, even though it's not even using ID's anywhere close to needing `bigint`.  I also don't want to change ID From `Integer` to `Long`, as I have OPTION STRICT ON in my VB projects, and I would have to change quite a few places...  So is there a way I can convert the value?  I tried `Convert.ToInt32(c.ID)`, of course getting the error ToInt32 is not a recognized SQL method.  I wasn't sure if there was a SQL Function, or even something implicit....

Comment: Have you tried casting the long to an int? I don't know the VB.NET syntax, but in C# I'd write something like `(int)c.ID`. IIRC EF-LINQ supports casts. SQL does support [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) but casts between `bigint` and `int` should be implicit.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... I don't know why I was overcomplicating it...  I will do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Can't `ReferenceItem.ID` be `long`? It will also accept `int` as value.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't like it in VB with option strict on... that was the problem with that.  You are right, it should, but with option strict on, if failed.